# how i can use EditValueChanged event with lookupedit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created lyaout controle that have lookupedit and texedit

```
                LayoutControl lc = new LayoutControl();
            lc.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            LookUpEdit steelstandard = new LookUpEdit();
            steelstandard.Properties.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
            steelstandard.Properties.DataSource = assembly.GetSteelStandard();
            steelstandard.Properties.DisplayMember = "Norme";
            steelstandard.Properties.ValueMember = "id";
            steelstandard.Properties.ShowHeader = false;
            steelstandard.EditValue = 1;

            TextEdit tolerance = new TextEdit();
            tolerance.ReadOnly = true;
            lc.AddItem(Resources.standard, steelstandard).TextVisible = true;
            lc.AddItem(Resources.tolerance, tolerance).TextVisible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(lc);
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lc.BestFit();
```

and i use this code to assign value to the textedit controle

```
int length = Convert.ToInt32(rowGridView1["Long mm"]);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(steelstandard.EditValue) == 1)
            {
                tolerance.Text = ((length / 5000) + 2).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                tolerance.Text = ((length / 10000) + 2).ToString();
            }
```

the code run fine but when the lookupedit value changed nothing happened i try to use this code

```
private void steelstandard_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tolerance.Refresh();
    }
```

but still nothing
how i can catch when the lookupedit value changed so i can assign new value to the textedit

Comment: seems you are missing to subscribe the event `steelstandard_EditValueChanged`

Comment: yes thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this code solve my problem

```
        void steelstandard_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)

        {
            DataRow rowGridView1 = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(rowGridView1["Long mm"]);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(steelstandard.EditValue) == 1)
            {
                tolerance.Text = string.Empty;
                tolerance.Text = ((length / 5000) + 2).ToString();
            }
            else
            {

                tolerance.Text = string.Empty;
                tolerance.Text = ((length / 10000) + 2).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    steelstandard.EditValueChanged += steelstandard_EditValueChanged;
```